# OnClickListener implemented in Adapter of RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener

I've implemented the following adapter for a RecyclerView. I've also included the code for handling clicks on RecyclerView items. But the click listener is not working.

```
class MyListAdapter(private val titles: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(titles[position])
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        private val myTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
        
        fun bind(title: String) {
            myTextView.text = title
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): MyViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.rv_row, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your view holder class:

```
init{
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

So, the final adapter will look like this:

```
class MyListAdapter(private val titles: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(titles[position])
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        private val myTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
        
        init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(title: String) {
            myTextView.text = title
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): MyViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.rv_row, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```